# wait / notifyAll not working as expected

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a class with two methods, one sends messages, the other confirm the message has been recevied/processed

```
   public void send(OTAHotelAvailRS otaHotelAvailRS) throws Exception {
        MessageAvailRs messageAvailRs = new MessageAvailRs();
        messageMap.put(messageAvailRs.getMessageId(), messageAvailRs);
        synchronized (messageAvailRs) {
            messagesSend++;
            messageAvailRs.wait();
            messageWake++;
        }
    }



 public void confirmMessage(String messageId) {
        logger.debug("Confirmed message: " + messageId);
        MessageAvailRs messageAvailRs = messageMap.remove(messageId);
        if (messageAvailRs != null) {
            synchronized (messageAvailRs) {
                messageAvailRs.notifyAll();
                messagesReceived++;
            }
        }
    }
```

When running in a multihread envoirnement (3 thread x 100 req) there are some messages don't wake up from the notify..

For example, once all message has been sent

```
messageSend = 100
messageRec = 100
messageWake = 98
```

And the size of the map is 0, There are no repeated messageIds.

I have shorten the case. It's more complex.

I have a service that each time a request is received the method send is called. This method (It's not in the code) send the message to a JMS Queue, other serivice receives this messages, process them and send a response to another JMSQueue, then a JMSConsumer reads the responses and calls the confirm method.

What is wrong ?

Comment: What does each thread do? Are many threads calling send and receiveMessage potientially at the same time?

Comment: Yes, they are called at same time by different threads. The send is called everytime a req is received on the serve.  The confirm is called by a JMS Consumer each time a message is processed. I have missed some code related with sending the mesages to a JMS queue and the JMS consumer

Comment: Damn! You are right. Here has to be the problem. I hava to check if the message has been received before to wait for the response.

Comment: Would it not be a lot simpler to have a multithreaded `send` that confirmed its own messages after sending them? Assuming it takes a time to send things, you can use an [Executor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) to empty a queue of outgoing messages, and there will be no waiting involved.

Answer (score 1):

You are using [`wait()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#) wrongly.

The `wait` method should always in a while loop like this:

```
synchronized (obj) {
     while (<condition does not hold>)
         obj.wait();
     ... // Perform action appropriate to condition
 }
```

Suppose Thread1 and Thread2 are waiting. Thread3 calls `notifyAll`. Thread1 wake up first, and consumes this condition. When it comes to Thread2 , Thread2 is supposed to check this condition again, if it is not satisfied, Thread2 should fall into another `wait`.

Comment: There is no wait condition. The wait and notify are used for synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to james large

The problem is that notifyAll() is called before the wait(). The solution is to use a boolean to no wait() if response has been received.

```
 public void send(OTAHotelAvailRS otaHotelAvailRS) throws Exception {
        MessageAvailRs messageAvailRs = new MessageAvailRs();
        messageMap.put(messageAvailRs.getMessageId(), messageAvailRs);
        synchronized (messageAvailRs) {
            messagesSend++;
            if  (!messageAvailRs.isConfirmed()) {
                messageAvailRs.wait();
            }
            messageWake++;
        }
    }

public void confirmMessage(String messageId) {
        logger.debug("Confirmed message: " + messageId);
        MessageAvailRs messageAvailRs = messageMap.remove(messageId);
        if (messageAvailRs != null) {
            meesageAvailRs.confirm();
            synchronized (messageAvailRs) {               
                messageAvailRs.notifyAll();
                messagesReceived++;
            }
        }
    }

public synchronized boolean isConfirmed() {
   return confimed;
}

public synchronized confirm() {
   cofirmed = true;
}
```

Comment: I suggest to change `if  (!messageAvailRs.isConfirmed())` to `while (!messageAvailRs.isConfirmed())`, as I said in my answer.